# How can i close this ng-template popover when a user submits?

Tags: angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

```
<ng-template #Question>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center" style="width: 250px">
      <textarea
        [(ngModel)]="questionInput"
        type="text"
        placeholder="ask a ?"
        class="w-90"
        style="height: 100px"
      ></textarea>
      <div class="w-90 m-2 d-flex justify-content-end">
        <button (click)="askQuestion()" class="btn">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

working in Angular 7, using ngbootstrap and i have this template which appears in a popover, called above from `[ngbPopover]="Question"` which is on a `<div>`. trying to figure out how to close the popover on click of submit. I've seen other answers which call a param `popover` from the typescript, but i dont have any such param in my code. thought that was the purpose of using nbbootstrap. I know there has to be an easy way i can tie the popover to a param that i toggle with a `(click)="..."` event listener. or can i add a param in the template to do this?

how can i close my popover on submit?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a reference variable in the element you make the popover and use the method close when submit

```
<!--see the #p="ngbPopover"-->
<div #p="ngbPopover" [ngbPopover]="Question" ...>
```

In you button

```
 <button (click)="p.close();askQuestion()" class="btn">
```

If you want mannage if, e.g. questionInput!="", you can also pass the reference variable to your function askQuestion

```
 <button (click)="askQuestion(p)" class="btn">
```

Your function askQuestion

```
askQuestion(p:NgbPopover)
{
  if (questionInput)
     p.close()
}
```

Comment: ill try this in a few, ill mark you for credit if it works. thanks!